# execute a method after 5 min ignoring reload in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, liferay-6

Hi I have some code in jsp, I'm working with liferay.
I have the next code:

```
<aui:form>

<aui:input label="user" name="user" type="text"
    showRequiredLabel="<%=false%>" value="<%=correo%>">
    <aui:validator name="email" />
    <aui:validator name="required" />
</aui:input>
<br>

<aui:input label="password" name="password" type="password"
    showRequiredLabel="<%=false%>" value="<%=password%>">
    <aui:validator name="required" />
</aui:input>
<br>`<aui:button-row>
    <aui:button type="submit" value="update"  />
    </aui:button-row>
</aui:form>
```

`

```
    <%ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(user, pass);
    service.setCredentials(credentials);
    service.setUrl(new java.net.URI(server));
    service.setTraceEnabled(true);  
    CalendarFolder cf=CalendarFolder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);
    FindItemsResults<Appointment> findResults = cf.findAppointments(
            new CalendarView(startDate, endDate));  

    for (Appointment appt : findResults.getItems())
    {
       appt.load();                
       appt.getSubject().toString();
       appt.getStart();
       appt.getEnd();
       appt.getLocation();          
}   
%>`
```

the problem is when I refresh the page execute "some lines of code" and is too slow, I want to execute this "some lines of code" after 5 minutes no matter if the page is refreshed some idea??
I want to execute this every five minutes, not in every refresh

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use ajax call for the parts you want to get executed after five minutes.  I hope this helps

```
<script>
//300000 = 5 minues
setInterval("yourAjaxCall()",300000);
function yourAjaxCall(){...}
</script>
```